# socket.io node.js with beaglebone issues

Tags: node.js, linux, socket.io, debian, beagleboneblack

I never normally post stuff here asking why something isn't working, but i've been struggling all day with this issue and hope that someone might be familiar with what's happening and could help.

I took an example from github on how to control GPIOs on the beaglebone black over wi-fi by using socket.io : github.com/lgxlogic/BoneScript-SocketIO

I'm not an expert with javascript but when I follow the exact instructions given and and run the HtmlLedDemo.js file, I get the following error below. My version of node is v.5.9.0 . I have tried updating socket.io and still the same problem. Many thanks in advance.

```
root@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9# node HtmlLedDemo.js
Option log level is not valid. Please refer to the README.
Option browser client minification is not valid. Please refer to the README.
Option browser client etag is not valid. Please refer to the README.
Server running on: http://192.168.0.87:8080
/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/bonescript/src/my.js:245
        callback(resp);
        ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
at onUnloadSlot (/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/bonescript/src/my.js:245:13)
at unloadSlot (/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/bonescript/src/my.js:235:13)
at onWriteSlots (/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/bonescript/src/my.js:210:43)
at onReadSlots (/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/bonescript/src/my.js:199:13)
at onFindCapeMgr (/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/bonescript/src/my.js:174:9)
at Object.exports.load_dt (/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/bonescript/src/my.js:157:5)
at onDTBOExists (/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/bonescript/src/my.js:332:26)
at onDTBOExistsTest (/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/bonescript/src/my.js:279:13)
at Object.exports.create_dt (/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/bonescript/src/my.js:274:9)
at Object.exports.setPinMode (/var/lib/cloud9/node_modules/bonescript/src/hw_capemgr.js:102:12)
root@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9#
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says "callback is not a function". If you have a look at the supplied call stack, you can see that on line 245 of your "my.js" file, you attempt to call a function by the variable name callback. What this error message tells you is that whatever this variable contains, it is not a function.

Comment: I know. This is one of the files that came with the bonescript installation tho.
 I'm not quite sure of the actual cause.

Comment: Given the title of the file and it's location in the 'bonescript/src' folder, it seems like a file editable/created via the Cloud9 IDE. Is this possibly part of your copy&pasted example? If it is truly completly 3rd party, then figure out how it's getting called out by your code as you are likely calling it with an argument that is not a callback function as it expects. Cant really do much more without seeing the file in question.

Comment: Looking a little more into this; in the bonescript repository for the given file (https://github.com/jadonk/bonescript/blob/master/src/my.js) we see that the callback that is attempted to be called on line 245 is supplied to the script via the fourth argument of the call to the function load_dt(). You'll have to figure out when you or your dependency calls that function and ensure the fourth argument is a callback function.